# Examples of well designed and secure web applications

Tags: security

Most people would be aware of [OWASP WebGoat](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) or Foundstone's [Hacme Books](http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources/proddesc/hacmebooks.htm) and [Hacme Bank](http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources/proddesc/hacmebank.htm). These are deliberately insecure applications to teach beginners about common security vulnerabilities.

On the contrary I have not been able to locate any application that is intentionally secure. Granted that no such application is completely secure, but are there any applications that would implement a collection of best practices that most other applications should follow ?

PS: To clarify my needs, I'm looking for a 'secure equivalent' of Webgoat, or even better, a secure [Pet Store](https://blueprints.dev.java.net/petstore/) application. Design tradeoffs for security, that are discussed in a paper/website/blog would be a bonus.

PPS: This is now community-wiki, especially since there can/could be several right answers - this is not language specific.

Answer (score 1):

The OWASP Guide contains this information.

Comment: Agreed. But I'm looking for application source code that can be studied. People make mistakes interpreting information :)

Comment: Or for that matter, not all security attributes can be incorporated into an application. I'm equally interested in the trade offs that have been taken during implementation.

Comment: Fair enough; I suppose no one has yet been brave enough to say 'here is the ultimate secure bank app' :) Maybe suggest it, work on it as an OWASP project. It's an arguably interesting idea.

Comment: My knowledge of cryptography is nil, but IMHO, 'secure' is a relative term... 

What is secure today may not be secure tomorrow, brute-force attacks may break whatever was deemed secure in earlier years. The same applies to algorithms e.g the weakness uncovered in the ENIGMA

Answer (score 0):

I think a more interesting question is "can you show me a code that can securely do X and Y" - reusable snippets of secure code that take some input and produce security-validated output.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The reason why the question is for a complete app as opposed to snippets of code, is more so because during construction of an app, one might regard a particular snippet of code to be more secure than others in certain contexts.

For instance, some applications (desktop ones) built in Java would store and manage passwords using byte arrays only (more secure than Strings which are almost always found in web apps). Any secure Java web app would have to live with that vulnerability. A snippet of code often does not expose this.