# Is there a .NET equivalent of WebGoat

Tags: .net, web-services, security

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303305/examples-of-well-designed-and-secure-web-applications) the [OWASP WebGoat](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3AOWASP_WebGoat_Project) project looks like a great way to learn about web security. Although the principles will equally to .NET applications I would prefer to use a .NET based application. Does anybody know of a suitable .NET alternative?

Comment: In 2023 there is: https://github.com/jerryhoff/WebGoat.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources-free-tools.asp

At this website, you can find multiple website simulations call Hacme something. The simulation you are looking for is **Hacme Bank**.

Hacme Travel is in C++

Hacme Bank is in .NET

Hacme Shipping is in ColdFusion

Hacme Casino is in Ruby on Rails

Hacme Book is in Java J2EE

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are looking for [HackMe Bank](http://www.foundstone.com/us/resources/proddesc/hacmebank.htm) which is written in ASP.Net.  There is also Google's [Jarlsberg](http://jarlsberg.appspot.com/) for python. for PHP there is [The White Box](http://code.google.com/p/thewhitebox/downloads/list) and [Damn Vulnerable Web App](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvwa/).